# unable to get spectrum colorpicker working

Tags: jquery, html, color-picker

I am trying to implement the spectrum colorpicker http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/

I have the spectrum css file and the spectrum js file and also jquery 1.9.0 file in the same folder as the html file.

All I am getting is a input box on the screen and no colorpicker. I have tried in firefox/chrome and IE but nothing.

I cant see anywhere where it says I need any additional files

Can anyone please help as I think its probably something really obvious

here is the code of the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spectrum.css ">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="spectrum.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(".my_color").spectrum({
        color: "#f00"
     });
   </script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <input type='text' class="my_color" />
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: try putting the `<script>` at the end of the page or use `$(document).ready(function(){ ...script here... });`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure to call your scripts after the DOM is finished loading e.g.,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".my_color").spectrum({
      color: "#f00"
   });
});
```

Works fine with the correct execution order: http://jsfiddle.net/xqdBd/

Notice how this: http://jsfiddle.net/xqdBd/1/ doesn't work anymore as the JavaScript is called before the DOM has finished loading.

Another problem is here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spectrum.css ">
```

Notice the extra space at the end of `"spectrum.css "`, that or your JavaScript files aren't being loaded. Without seeing the page you are using it is impossible to tell.

Comment: I found that the js $(".my_color").spectrum({
    color: "#f00"
}); needs to go afetre the input and now working

Comment: @BarryWatts It doesn't have to go after. It just means it gets evaluated after. It is still good practice to `$(document).ready()` as you ensure the DOM is finished before loading JavaScript and your JavaScript can go anywhere on the page.

Comment: Just to add `$(function(){});` is shorthand for `$(document).ready( function(){});`

Answer (score -3):

The js

```
$(".my_color").spectrum({
    color: "#f00"
});
```

has to go after the input box

Comment: As the above answer states, it does not have to be placed after the affected element. It simply must *evaluate* after the input has been loaded on the page.